# Why won't my JavaScript load on my webpage (using window.onload)?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dreamweaver, onload

I'm trying to develop an HTML Page within Adobe Dreamweaver using the Live Preview function (where I view the webpage on a local server) and my JavaScript is being finicky. Im trying to populate a dropdown menu with a JS array and my previous testing worked, but now when I try to get the script to run automatically, either 
a) nothing happens or
b) the button flashes suggesting it was updated but still shows blank. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    <script>
    function start() {

        var arrOptions = []; //arrOptionsCollection with HTML tags
        var arrOptionsCollection = [0, 1, 2]; //Values for dropdown

        arrOptions.push("<option value='Select From List...'>Select From List...</option>") //Dropdown Default


        //Adds HTML tags to arrOptionsCollections
        for (var i=0, n = arrOptionsCollection.length; i < n; i++) { =
            arrOptions.push("<option value='" + arrOptionsCollection[i] + "'>" + arrOptionsCollection[i] + "</option>");
        }

        //Transfers arrOptions to actual HTML
        document.getElementById("district-select").innerHTML = arrOptions.join();
    }

    document.getElementById("form-select").onload = function() {start()};

</script>
```

```
<body onload="start();">
<form id="form-select">
    <select id="district-select">
        <!--Script Inserts Options Here-->
    </select>

</form>
```

Comment: Look at the console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: I'm using JS inline with HTML so I don't have a console. which definitely makes things tricky :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder what's the role of the `=` at the beginning of your `for` loop. Simply, it doesn't make any sense.
So instead of:

```
for (var i=0, n = arrOptionsCollection.length; i < n; i++) { =
```

Put:

```
for (var i=0, n = arrOptionsCollection.length; i < n; i++) {
```

Here is your code:

```js
function start() {

        var arrOptions = []; //arrOptionsCollection with HTML tags
        var arrOptionsCollection = [0, 1, 2]; //Values for dropdown

        arrOptions.push("<option value='Select From List...'>Select From List...</option>") //Dropdown Default


        //Adds HTML tags to arrOptionsCollections
        for (var i=0, n = arrOptionsCollection.length; i < n; i++) {
            arrOptions.push("<option value='" + arrOptionsCollection[i] + "'>" + arrOptionsCollection[i] + "</option>");
        }

        //Transfers arrOptions to actual HTML
        document.getElementById("district-select").innerHTML = arrOptions.join();
    }

    document.getElementById("form-select").onload = function() {start()};
```

```html
<body onload="start();">
<form id="form-select">
    <select id="district-select">
        <!--Script Inserts Options Here-->
    </select>

</form>
```

Here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/yLYbYjw?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you so much for all that. You are indeed right about that equal sign (probably a typo that my eyes glossed over after staring at the code for so long) and I had a sort of success. Viewing the program in Dreamweaver, the code runs as it should. However, in the live preview page (I'm using Safari), its still blank. Im assuming this has something to do with Dreamweaver? Nonetheless, some success beats no success and staring frustratedly at my code while trying to debug by reading it aloud. If you have any idea why the preview won't work - awesome. If not, no worries and thanks so much!